# kendo-ui mobile loader looks off

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, kendo-ui

My kendo-mobile-loader looks broken, and I didn't change anything in the css, it is a fresh install via `bower install kendo-ui-core` and no other css libraries are included. I am using it with `angularjs`

Looks like this:

[image: kendo-ui broken loader]

My included files are:

`styles/kendo.common.core.min.css`

`styles/kendo.flat.mobile.min.css`

Filed it as a bug in Github, but they redirected me here, so apparently this behaviour is related to me...
I tried it in several browsers like Google Chrome, Firefox and IE 11 it's everywhere the same.

In the official documentation, they state, that including this file alone should work:
`/styles/kendo.mobile.flat.min.css`, but it simply does not…

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out, what the problem was.
`kendo.mobile.*.min.css` is sufficient but you need to "activate" it in the javascript, whatsoever.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="kendo.mobile.flat.min.css">

<script>
  new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body, { skin: 'flat' });
</script>
```

or for Angular

```
<kendo-mobile-application k-skin="'flat'">
    ...
    ...
</kendo-mobile-application>
```

Unfortunately, this flat theme differs a lot from the original web variant.
I had to restyle it with the help of [kendo flat themes](http://kendoflatthemes.com/), and the [mobile theme builder](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobilethemebuilder/).